# what is the use of endpoint parameter in add_resource() in flask restful api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I have written two api's , one is to create device(POST) and other one is list out all the device(GET) .

```py
in app.py
---------
# Get the List of the devices
api.add_resource(DeviceDetail, "/v1/t/device/")
# Create new Devices
api.add_resource(DeviceDetail, "/v1/t/device/create")

in controller/device.py
class DeviceDetail(Resource):
      def get(): 
         #some code to list out all the device and return the response
      def post():
         #some code to insert the record to db and return the response
```

AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: devicedetail.

if i will pass endpoint parameter to add_resource() thn i am not getting any error.

```py
# Get the List of the devices
api.add_resource(DeviceDetail, "/v1/t/device/",endpoint='get_the_list_of_deives')
# Create new Devices
api.add_resource(DeviceDetail, "/v1/t/device/create",endpoint='create_the_deivce')
```

so i am confused ,what it does here.

Answer (score 0):

[Flask documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.Api.add_resource) says:

> endpoint (str) – endpoint name (defaults to Resource.**name**.lower() Can be used to reference this route in fields.Url fields

If you don't provide endpoint Flask will create default one for you and your error clearly states what the problem is. `View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: devicedetail`